# Размер символа немоноширинного шрифта

Tags: шрифты, c++

Есть текстура, в ней нарисованы все необходимые символы шрифтом Comic Sans. Необходимо в программе (c++) вырезать из текстуры эти символы. Есть прямой способ - вручную указать координаты, это не катит, ибо пару дней точно выкину.

Есть ли способ узнать размер любого символа определенного шрифта (ширина, высота)?

Comment: Не знаю, в каком таком гуе Вы пишете (они разные), но в любом есть вызовы, которые вместо отрисовки строки выдают её размер (или изменение координат на листе/в окне). Что касается размера символа -- есть ответ @niki-timofe, но если Вы хотите рисовать не один символ, а больше, то следует учитывать например кернинг (если он есть у шрифта)

Comment: @alexlz, Свое гуи, точно знаю шрифт, размер. Нужно из текстуры вырезать символы и составлять из них надписи!

Comment: Мсье знает толк...

Можно написать классификатор (как в OCR), который найдет границы отдельных символов. Стоит ли этим заниматься ради того, чтобы сделать растровый шрифт, да еще и Comic Sans — вопрос спорный. :)

Comment: @drdaeman Чем-то напоминает, как преступники и революционеры из газет-журналов вырезали буквы и составляли послания. Чтобы не нашли, кто это дело мастерил.

Comment: А какой смысл всей этой фигнёй заниматься?, Напишите зачем это вам нужно, быть может, есть более простое решение...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, почитать [документацию](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/Fonts/family.aspx?FID=3) к шрифту.

Comment: По ссылке нет ничего подобного.